# Plone, Archetypes: Change a TextField from text/plain to text/html

Tags: python, plone, archetypes, plone-4.x

I have a family of Plone sites which use Archetypes-based contents.

I have some `TextField`s which need to be changed from `text/plain` to `text/html`; say, the schema snipped

```
TextField(
      name='summary',
      default='',
      read_permission=Access_contents_information,
      default_content_type='text/plain',
      allowable_content_types=('text/plain',),
      storage=AnnotationStorage(migrate=True),
      widget=TextAreaWidget(
          label=_('my_label_summary',
                  default='Summary'),
          i18n_domain='plone',
      ),
  ),
```

should change to something like

```
TextField(
      name='summary',
      default='',
      read_permission=Access_contents_information,
      default_content_type='text/html',
      default_output_type='text/html',
      allowable_content_types=('text/html',),
      storage=AnnotationStorage(migrate=True),
      widget=RichWidget(
          label=_('my_label_summary',
                  default='Summary'),
          i18n_domain='plone',
      ),
  ),
```

Since the number of objects is small, I'd be willing to accept a temporary ugly appearance of the affected fields (e.g. collapsed linebreaks); more important is to have the visual editor (which doesn't work for me with switchable content types).

The best solution would of course be to have the current `text/plain` fields used as they are, and when about to edit the object, have them converted to a reasonable `text/html` equivalent, which can then be edited nicely with the visual editor (CKEditor, in my case).

However, if I simply edit the object with the changed schema, the visual editor looks fine, but the stored text is surrounded by `<p>` / `</p>` tags and interpreted as `text/plain`.

I found `/archetype_tool/manage_updateSchemaForm`, but updating the schema for my class there didn't help.

I found https://plone.org/products/archetypes/documentation/old/ArchetypesDeveloperGuide/, but this looks both incomplete and outdated.

Any pointers? Thank you!

**Update:**

Since this won't fit in a comment:
I have created an `upgrades` subpackage now; `configure.zcml`:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
    i18n_domain="plone">

    <genericsetup:upgradeStep
        source="*"
        destination="1001"
        title="text/html fields for MyType"
        profile="Products.myproduct:default"
        handler=".to_1001.fix_mimetypes"/>

</configure>
```

Module code (`to_1001.py`):

```
import logging
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
from ..tools.log import getLogSupport

logger, debug_active, DEBUG = getLogSupport(fn=__file__)

def htmlify_attribute(o, attr_name, brain=None, default=u''):
    """
    Change MIME type of a TextField to text/html
    """
    attr = getattr(o, attr_name, None)
    changed = False

    brain_url = (brain is not None
                 and brain.getURL()
                 or None)
    if not attr:
        mutator = o.getField(attr_name).getMutator(o)
        mutator(default)
        attr = getattr(o, attr_name, None)
        changed = True

    convert = False
    mimetype = getattr(attr, 'mimetype', 'text/plain')
    if mimetype != 'text/html':
        if brain_url is not None:
            logger.info('Fixing MIME type of %(attr_name)s'
                        ' for %(brain_url)s', locals())
        setattr(attr, 'mimetype', 'text/html')
        changed = True

    return changed

def fix_mimetypes(context):
    """
    text/plain --> text/html for some MyType fields
    """
    pc = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
    TYPES = ['MyType']
    brains = pc.unrestrictedSearchResults(portal_type=TYPES)
    total = len(brains)
    MASK = 'Fixing MIME types for %(total)d %(TYPES)s objects'
    logger.info(MASK + ' ...', locals())
    cnt = 0

    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    for brain in brains:
        obj = brain.getObject()
        if htmlify_attribute(obj, 'summary', brain):
            cnt += 1

    if cnt or True:
        logger.info('%(cnt)d objects changed', locals())
    logger.info(MASK + ': DONE', locals())
    return ('Done '+MASK) % locals()
```

Since my product lacked a [special profile version](http://docs.plone.org/4/en/develop/addons/components/genericsetup.html#increment-profile-version), I created a `.../profiles/default/metadata.xml` file and set a value of `1000`; since nothing happened on startup and nothing special could be observed in the QuickInstaller, I re-installed, and then increased the number by one.

My `to_1001` module is imported on startup, as I can see by the registration of a logger
(which is logged); but it is not *used* (as I know because of
`pdb.set_trace()`), neither when starting up (`bin/instance fg`) with an increased version number nor when re-installing in the QuickInstaller.

What is missing?
How is this upgrade step supposed to work, i.e. to be triggered?

Answer (score 2):

You may need an upgrade step for existing objects. See for example eea.soercontent [evolve19.py](https://github.com/eea/eea.soercontent/blob/master/eea/soercontent/upgrades/evolve19.py)  and [configure.zcml](https://github.com/eea/eea.soercontent/blob/master/eea/soercontent/upgrades/configure.zcml#L88)

To test if this is the case, before writing the upgrade step, go to **Edit** and **Save** without changing anything. Now if you go to Edit again, you should have your Rich Text Editor in place.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I'll need an upgrade step; I'll look into this. My main problem is not the get the rich text editor but to get the content types right.

Comment: I updated my question with my efforts of creating an upgrade step. How is this supposed to work, i.e. to be triggered?

Comment: Put version `1001` within `profiles/default/metadata.xml` and then your upgrade step should appear within `Site Setup > Add-ons` or via ZMI: `portal_setup > manage_upgrades`

Answer (score 1):

I have used this code for two clients now, to initialise new rich text fields.  I guess it does not matter if they are old or new fields.  This function takes a content instance as input.  So you can iterate over catalog brains and pass this function `brain.getObject()`.

```
def initialize_rich_text_fields(instance):
    """New rich text fields should have mimetype text/html.

    Adapted from setDefaults in Archetypes BasicSchema.
    """
    default_output_type = 'text/x-html-safe'
    mimetype = 'text/html'
    schema = instance.Schema()
    for field in schema.values():
        # We only need to do this for fields with one specific mimetype.
        if not shasattr(field, 'default_output_type'):
            continue
        if field.default_output_type != default_output_type:
            continue
        # only touch writable fields
        mutator = field.getMutator(instance)
        if mutator is None:
            continue
        base_unit = field.getBaseUnit(instance)
        if base_unit.mimetype == mimetype:
            continue
        # If content has already been set, we respect it.
        if base_unit:
            continue
        default = field.getDefault(instance)
        args = (default,)
        kw = {'field': field.__name__,
              '_initializing_': True}
        kw['mimetype'] = mimetype
        mapply(mutator, *args, **kw)
```

Comment: Ah, interesting (although perhaps not *exactly* what I need). Should `text/x-html-safe` be used as the `default_output_type` for *every* field which might contain `text/plain` or `text/html`?

Comment: Sorry - I hesited a second too long to edit the previous comment ...
So `text/x-html-safe` is about stripping dangerous HTML tags and is advisable for any user-contributed contents.
There is not by chance a standard conversion to turn simple `text/plain` (text paragraphs and bullet lists) to HTML, right? I'm sorry - it's `text/plain` in my objects, not `text/structured` or the like ...

Comment: Plone ships with the portal_transform tool in Products.PortalTransforms. You can use that to transform from one mime type to another.